# Filter file list in python/ lowercase and uppercase extension files

Tags: python-3.x, filter, lambda

I am filtering my file list using this line:

*MyList = filter(lambda x: x.endswith(('.doc','.txt','.dat')), os.listdir(path))*

The line above will only filter lowercase extension files. Therefore, is there an elegant way to make it filter also the uppercase extension files?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add a `.lower()` to your lambda function

```
MyList = filter(lambda x: x.lower().endswith(('.doc','.txt','.dat')), os.listdir(path))
```

I'd prefer to use `os.path.splitext` with a list comprehension

```
from os.path import splitext
my_list = [x for x in os.listdir(path) if splitext(x)[1].lower() in {'.doc', '.txt', '.dat'}]
```

Still a bit much for a single line, so perhaps

```
from os.path import splitext

def valid_extension(x, valid={'.doc', '.txt', '.dat'}):
    return splitext(x)[1].lower() in valid

my_list = [x for x in os.listdir(path) if valid_extension(x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import re
pat = re.compile(r'[.](doc|txt|dat)$', re.IGNORECASE)
filenames = [filename for filename in os.listdir(path)
             if re.search(pat, filename)]
print(filenames)
```